# migration springBoot2 to Springboot 3 from restClient to webClient

Tags: httpclient, spring-webclient, java-17, spring-boot-3

actually i'am migration from springboot 2 to 3 and i'am struggling in httpClient configuration of spring WebClient and my question is :

which http client to use ? java 17 net.httpClient , netty reactor , or could we keep apache http client .
I need to keep ssl , caching mecanism and pooling, but in netty we don't have all these features , here is a code snippet of my configuration with springboot 2 :

```
  return new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .requestFactory(() -> {
                    CacheConfig cacheConfig = CacheConfig.custom()
                            .setMaxCacheEntries(100)
                            .build();
                    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                            .setConnectTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .setSocketTimeout(5000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .build();

                    HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = CachingHttpClients.custom()
                            .setCacheConfig(cacheConfig)
                            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig);

                    SslStore truststore = backendProperties.getTruststore();
                    SslStore keystore = backendProperties.getKeystore();
                    if (truststore != null && truststore.getPath() != null && keystore != null && keystore.getPath() != null) {
                        LayeredConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SslUtils.readSSLSocketFactory(truststore.getPath(), truststore.getPassword(), keystore.getPath(), keystore.getPassword());
                        if (sslSocketFactory != null) {
                            httpClientBuilder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
                        }
                    }

                    HttpClient client = httpClientBuilder.build();
                    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
                })
                .build();
```

thanks